# Change Platform Target on Third Party .NET Assembly

Tags: .net, clr

How do I change the 'Platform Target' on compiled assemblies without having access to the source?

For this particular instance, I have an compiled, .NET assembly as a DLL that is marked as `x86` and I need to change it to `AnyCPU`.

Why?:

- Trouble dealing with this issue:
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/19/resgen-exe-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format.aspx
- Trouble with third party providers leaving assemblies on `AnyCPU` when dependant on `x86` libs.
- Trouble with third party providers leaving assemblies on `x86` when platform independant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with CorFlags utility: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to realize that the library developer set the x86 because of a dependency on a DLL that is 32bit only.

More than likely what you have to do is compile your own project to x86, rather than the other way around.

It sucks, but there is probably a good reason that the developer set it to x86 rather than leaving the default of AnyCPU...